# Basic SQL Joining Tables

Tags: sql

Having a bit of trouble with a basic SQL problem.

The question is that I have to find the salespersons first and last name, then their Social Insurance Number, the product description, the product price, and quantity sold where the total quantity sold is greater than 5.

I'll attach the database information below as a photo.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: So far what I have is the following: Select
  FirstName, LastName, SIN
 From
  Salesmen Inner Join 
But now I'm not sure how to join the three tables that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product quantity sold greater than 5

```
SELECT ProductId
FROM ProductsSales 
HAVING SUM(QuantitySold) > 5
```

Use that to get the rest:

```
SELECT s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.SIN, p.ProductDescription, ps.UnitSalesPrice, ps.QuantitySold
FROM ProductsSales ps
LEFT JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = ps.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Salesmen s on s.SalesmaneID = ps.SellerID
WHERE ps.ProductID IN 
   (
      SELECT ProductId
      FROM ProductsSales 
      GROUP BY ProductId
      HAVING SUM(QuantitySold) > 5
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.SIN, c.ProductDescription, b.UnitSalesPrice, b.QuantitySold
FROM Salesmen a
LEFT JOIN ProductsSales b
ON a.SalesmanId = b.SellerId
LEFT JOIN Products c
ON b.ProductId = c.ProductId
WHERE b.QuantitySold > 5
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much! Are the letters "a", "b", and "c" simply the three different tables that are being joined?

Comment: @Brad yes alias are used to identify tables

Comment: @Hogan i think op meant only where quantity sold is greater than 5

Comment: @Hogan correct. Just have to find the salespersons name and all the other info where total quantity sold is greater than 5.

Comment: @Brad -- total quantity by this one salesperson or all salesperson.  If it is all salesperson as your question suggests than look at my answer.

Comment: @Hogan it is for whoever has greater than 5. So yours is the most correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.SIN From Salesmen as a, 
   c.ProductDescriptio, c.Price, b.sum(QunatitySold)
inner join ProductSales as b on a.Salesmanid = b.sellerid
inner join Products as c on c.ProductId = b.ProductId
having b.sum(QunatitySold)> 5
group by a.FirstName, b.ProductDescription
```

Comment: Isn't the total number sold > 5 for all sales people.  This is grouped by both sales person and product type.

Comment: If the query select the price and description then i think the aggregation level is  also for Product .. (and for person)

Answer (score 1):

Brad,

Welcome to SQL. Joining for me was a terrifying experience when I first started but its really easy. The general concept is this:

**Pick a Join**

If you want to see all records that would be common between the two table, you would use and `JOIN`. If you wanted to combine the two tables but still show all records you use `LEFT JOIN`

The basic syntax is

```
SELECT fieldnames FROM tablename alias
JOIN othertable alias ON firstalias.field = secondalias.field
--Example
SELECT animal, food, idtag from animals a
JOIN food f on a.animalid = f.animalid
```

This assumes you have a common field animalid in both the animals table and the food table. you should also ideally preface the field names with the alias to make it easier to understand like this: `a.animal, f.food`

And you keep going until you have joined all the tables you need.
Make sure you only request field names you want

Hope that helps